# Non-italicized tick labels with pgf in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, pgf

I am using the `pgf` backend in `matplotlib 1.5.3` to produce publication-quality figures. Here is how I set up the plotting script.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.use('pgf')
pgf_with_latex = {                      # setup matplotlib to use latex for output
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",        # change this if using xetex or lautex
    "text.usetex": True,                # use LaTeX to write all text
    "font.family": "sans-serif",
    "font.sans-serif": "Bitstream Vera Sans, Helvetica, Computer Modern Sans Serif",
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",    # use utf8 fonts because your computer can handle it :)
        r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",        # plots will be generated using this preamble
        r"\usepackage{textcomp}",
        r"\usepackage{sfmath}",             # sets math in sans-serif
    ]
    }
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def newfig():
    plt.clf()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 2))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    return fig, ax

fig, ax = newfig()
ax.set_xlabel("Some x-label text")
plt.gcf().tight_layout()
plt.savefig(os.getcwd() + "/test.pdf")
plt.savefig(os.getcwd() + "/test.eps")
```

I am using the package `sfmath` to set all math environments in `sans-serif`. At the end I save in `.pdf` and `.eps` format. Here's the problem: While the `pdf`clearly uses `sans-serif` font everywhere, the `eps` file uses `serif` for all tick labels (not axis labels)! When I modify my LaTeX template to use `sfmath` it does not change the tick labels.

How can I prevent the `eps`from using `serif` font in the tick labels?

**Edit:** After a good day of experimenting, the only (barely) satisfying solution I found was to use `.tiff` as format, since this is also allowed by the journal. `eps` just seems to have problems and always turns out different than the `pdf` or other image formats.

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question to include the matplotlib version you are using (there are differences between 1.5 and 2.0 concerning ticklabel fonts). You may also replace *the rest of the program* with something that constitutes a minimal example, that allows everyone to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Done and done. I am using matplotlib 1.5.3

Comment: There is a square bracket missing somewhere, but the issue is reproducible in matplotlib 2.0. To me it seems that the `\usepackage{sfmath}` is simply ignored, because also formulas like `$x$` in the labels are written in serif font in the eps. Since eps files produced by matplotlib anyways [do not look very good](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html#postscript-options) *("[unacceptable] results, because the text is coarsely rasterized and converted to bitmaps, which are not scalable like standard postscript, and the text is not searchable.")* you may want to create the eps externally?!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the missing bracket was a copy/paste error. I will think about handing in a `pdf` for my submission instead of an `eps`. Still, an answer would help me a lot.